# UITextField Black Pixels at Edges

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I've created a UITextField programmatically with the following code:

```
self._maxPriceField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
self._maxPriceField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self._maxPriceField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self._maxPriceField.font            = fieldFont;
self._maxPriceField.delegate        = self;
```

The problem I'm having is that my UITextField ends up having these strange black pixels on the edges. This happens both on the device and in the simulator. You can see in the screenshot below:

When I create the same UITextField using IB, with the same specs and background, I have no problem. Unfortunately I need to create this UITextField programmatically.

Has anybody seen this before? What to do?

[image: You can see the black pixels at the edge of the UITextField here, right in the middle of the left edge.]

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is the way textfields are drawn on the screen.  I played around with your code a little bit, and if I set the text field height lower than about 20, you start to see a noticeable "shadow" that is clearly not drawn correctly.

My suggestion is to either use a height of 20 or higher for the text field, or to use a different style, such as Bezel or Line and set the background to white.

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:
[image]

And here is the code I used to draw these:

```
int labelWidth = 100;
int labelHeight = 10;

_maxPriceField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
_maxPriceField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
_maxPriceField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

//_maxPriceField.font            = fieldFont;
//_maxPriceField.delegate        = self;
[self.view addSubview:_maxPriceField];

UITextField *secondField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, labelWidth, labelHeight + 10)];
secondField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:secondField];
[secondField release];

UITextField *thirdField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, labelWidth, labelHeight + 20)];
thirdField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:thirdField];
[thirdField release];

UITextField *fourthField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, labelWidth, labelHeight + 30)];
fourthField.borderStyle     = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:fourthField];
[fourthField release];

UITextField *noRoundFirst = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 160, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
noRoundFirst.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
noRoundFirst.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:noRoundFirst];
[noRoundFirst release];
```

Hope this helps.

Mk